# Generate a sequence which is an increasing part of another vector in R

Tags: r, vector, sequence

First of all, sorry for the title. i tried to find an appropriate title.
My "problem" is that I have a vector, say 1-5 from which I would like to make a new vector. Which goes
    1, 1,2 , 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4,5

So for each round in includes one new number from the baseline vector until it reaches the end. I have a feeling it should be possible with seq...

Answer (score 3):

See `?sequence` (from the manpage):

For each element of `nvec` the sequence `seq_len(nvec[i])` is created. These are concatenated and the result returned.

example:

```
sequence(1:5)
[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: would that work for a POSIXct string? For some reason my RAM get blown out, even when I only use a small subsett with 128 dates..

Comment: @EndreGrünerOfstad: `nvec` contains the endpoints. `as.double(Sys.time)` gives you something like `1346080308`. This will result in a vector: `1:1346080308` (and similar for all you 128 dates). What do you want to do with your POSIXct values? Maybe you have to modify your question or ask a new one to better describe your problem.