# generate increasing sequence of varying length in R

Tags: r, sequence

Given n, generate a sequence like this:
   `0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, ........, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ....n`

Let's say n=3, then the sequence should be:
   `0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3`

I've tried using rep, but it only generates a fixed length, where as I need the sequence length to increase each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12109926/3710546)

```
n <- 3
sequence(0:(n+1))-1
# [1] 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: thanks. what's the difference between seq and sequence?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simply `Map` with an `unlist` to get the result you want

```
n <- 3
unlist(Map(seq, from=0, to=0:n))
# [1] 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 3
```